# Bootstrap 2 Carousel cycle once and then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Bootstrap 2 Carousel cycle once and then stop.** I suppose I am a bit lost as to how to make this happen! Ive tried cycle and interval but i just cant find enough documentation on how to make this specific function

Edit --- My code is pretty simple!

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"><!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><img src="images/carousel/slide-1.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/carousel/slide-2.png" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/carousel/slide-3.png" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 2500
})
</script>
```

Comment: I guess if you down vote my question you should at least tell me why. If it was obvious i wouldnt be asking

Comment: I'm guessing its because when you ask a question your supposed to demonstrate what you have done to solve the problem.. e.g. Show some code or give some example demonstrating your issue ie. `http://jsfiddle.net/' or `bootply.com`

Comment: "I suppose I am a bit lost as to how to make this happen!" I could post my html markup but that would be kinda silly since everyone knows it. Ive done nothing in terms of the js functions as indicated by my statement of being lost as to how to execute it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<script>
   var imgCount = 3;
   $('#myCarousel').carousel({
       interval: 2500
   });
   $('#myCarousel').bind('slid',function(){
      imgCount--;
      if(imgCount == 0)
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');  
   });
</script>
```

Comment: still not stopping, just tried interval:false instead of pause too
see http://ent1.development.webdesign-toledo.com

Comment: If you don't want it to go back to the start you can always set `imgCount = 2` instead.

Comment: Here let me give you an example.  http://www.bootply.com/90198  It should work as long as you have jquery and the proper Bootstrap js/css files loaded..

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to obtain what you actually need. Just replace the first line in your code with this one,

`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-wrap="false"><!-- Carousel items -->`

And then it should cycle only once.
Hope this helps you.

Cheers!!!

Comment: This really worked ! It stops on last image, is there any way we can stop it on first image?