# How to stop bootstrap carousel on first cylce

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want a slider to start sliding and it should stop at first cycle on first image of the slide/carousel.

```
var imgCount = 3;
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2500
});
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid',function(){
    imgCount--;
    if(imgCount == 3)
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');  
});
```

I also tried following code.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2500
});
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid',function(){
    var count = 3;

    count--;
    if(count == 0)
    {

        slide.stopAutoPlay();
    }

});
```

For some reason its not working. I am using stript tag right after bootstrap script file source.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the HTML code you're using for this specific element

Comment: @BradleyWilson why do you need html of carsusel ? its controlled by js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 2 Carousel cycle once and then stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599804/bootstrap-2-carousel-cycle-once-and-then-stop)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя some problems when debugging can start with typos, obviously i'd assume the op has checked for this. but for clarity. if it's deemed unecassary to ask, i'll take note.

Comment: @BradleyWilson no no its not unnecessary to ask , feel free to ask whatever you think is appropriate and can be helpful to solve question :)

Comment: I am using following html @BradleyWilson  http://www.bootply.com/new?visual=1#

Comment: unfortunately buddy it's showing blank, i'm unwilling to sign up to that website to view it. If you can have a look at the duplicate question provided by @NullPoiиteя or create a fresh JSFiddle (www.jsfiddle.net). it doesn't require any signing up, add the code, just click update and put the link into your question. (make sure you have the correct version of boostrap applied on the left navigation panel)

Comment: I tried but still did no work. I can make it stop at last image but I want to stop it on first image @BradleyWilson

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kefqkm55/, i uploaded html there @BradleyWilson

Comment: @NullPoiиteя interval:2500 working fine but carousel is not stopping on first image, its keep looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrap option serves to stop the carousel on the first cycle. But it remains on the last page after it has completed.

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="false">
```

or

```
$('.carousel').carousel({ wrap: false });
```

If you want it to stop at a specific slide count this code will help you to achieve that

```
var count = 1;

$('.carousel').carousel();
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) {
        $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
    }
});
```

**{Edit}**

Also if you want to reset the carousel's position and move to the first page after stopping you add this after pausing

```
var count = 1;

$('.carousel').carousel();
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) {
        $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
        // Reset the carousel position
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.carousel').carousel(0);
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

You need to set a timeout to allow the transition to finish or the carousel might have glitches after it has completed.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan as if this answer is working fine and helpful please accept this answer , so we can close new same type question as duplicate of this

Comment: I am i suppose to do it yesterday, Thanks again